# Why doesn't requests.get() return? What is the default timeout that requests.get() uses?

Tags: python, get, python-requests

In my script, `requests.get` never returns:

```
import requests

print ("requesting..")

# This call never returns!
r = requests.get(
    "http://www.some-site.example",
    proxies = {'http': '222.255.169.74:8080'},
)

print(r.ok)
```

What could be the possible reason(s)? Any remedy? What is the default timeout that `get` uses?

Comment: @user2357112: Does it matter? I doubt.

Comment: It definitely matters. If you provide the URL you're trying to access and the proxy you're trying to use, we can see what happens when we try to send similar requests.

Comment: @user2357112: Alright. Edited the question.

Comment: Your proxy is also incorrect. You must specify it like so: `proxies={'http': 'http://222.255.169.74:8080'}`. That could be why it isn't completing without a timeout.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

> What is the default timeout that get uses?

The default timeout is `None`, which means it'll wait (hang) until the connection is closed.

Just [specify a timeout value](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#timeouts), like this:

```
r = requests.get(
    'http://www.example.com',
    proxies={'http': '222.255.169.74:8080'},
    timeout=5
)
```

Comment: I think you're right. `None` means infinite (or "wait until the connection is close"). If I pass timeout myself, it returns!

Comment: @User timeout works just as fine with https as it does with http

Comment: This seems really hard to find in the docs by googling or otherwise.  Anyone know where this shows up in the docs?

Comment: @wordsforthewise http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts

Comment: Thanks, doing `print(requests.request.__doc__)` in IPython is more of what I was looking for though.  I was wondering what other optional arguments to `request.get()` there were.

Comment: Isn't this a bad design?!

Comment: @Ehsan88 Huh? No. What are you talking about?

Comment: @Ehsan88 Even with the `timeout` parameter?

Comment: @ronrothman I'm just saying that it makes sense if the request assume a default timeout like 30s instead of going forever when no timeout is provided. Just like other request libraries.

Comment: @Ehsan88 I see, thanks for clarifying. Your comment just says “this,” which makes it sound like my answer is a bad design; when what you really mean is that `requests.get` is a bad design.

Comment: Docs for timeout: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts

Comment: Docs seem to have moved, the above domains fail, new location: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#timeouts

Comment: For me on python 3.8 requests module was working weird. The server returns very fast less than  1ms. But if I don't define a timeout or give a time of high value of say 5 seconds, the response will show after about 2 seconds. I had to explicitly set a put a timeout of around 10ms or lesser to get the response as soon as server sent it.

Comment: I find the default of "indefinite" as a timeout contradicting to the lib's statement of "requests for humans". I would NOT assume that the default is "indefinite" and that I have to painfully remember at ANY and EVERY use of the library to define a timeout, because otherwise it might "magically" hang forever if my code throws a request right before my ISP changes my IP. Took me weeks to figure out that this issue only happened thanks to the lack of a reasonable default timeout, which EVERY other http library I've ever used had...

Answer (score 46):

From [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts):

> You can tell Requests to stop waiting for a response after a given
>   number of seconds with the timeout parameter:
>
> ```
> >>> requests.get('http://github.com', timeout=0.001)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> requests.exceptions.Timeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=80): Request timed out. (timeout=0.001)
> ```
>
> Note:
>
> timeout is not a time limit on the entire response download; rather,
>   an exception is raised if the server has not issued a response for
>   timeout seconds (more precisely, if no bytes have been received on the
>   underlying socket for timeout seconds).

It happens a lot to me that requests.get() takes a very long time to return even if the `timeout` is 1 second. There are a few way to overcome this problem:

**1. Use the `TimeoutSauce` internal class**

From: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1928#issuecomment-35811896

> ```
> import requests from requests.adapters import TimeoutSauce
>
> class MyTimeout(TimeoutSauce):
>     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>         if kwargs['connect'] is None:
>             kwargs['connect'] = 5
>         if kwargs['read'] is None:
>             kwargs['read'] = 5
>         super(MyTimeout, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>
> requests.adapters.TimeoutSauce = MyTimeout
> ```
>
> This code should cause us to set the read timeout as equal to the
>   connect timeout, which is the timeout value you pass on your
>   Session.get() call. (Note that I haven't actually tested this code, so
>   it may need some quick debugging, I just wrote it straight into the
>   GitHub window.)

**2. Use a fork of requests from kevinburke:** https://github.com/kevinburke/requests/tree/connect-timeout

From its documentation: https://github.com/kevinburke/requests/blob/connect-timeout/docs/user/advanced.rst

> If you specify a single value for the timeout, like this:
>
> ```
> r = requests.get('https://github.com', timeout=5)
> ```
>
> The timeout value will be applied to both the connect and the read
>   timeouts. Specify a tuple if you would like to set the values
>   separately:
>
> ```
> r = requests.get('https://github.com', timeout=(3.05, 27))
> ```

NOTE: [The change has since been merged to the main Requests project](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/1801).

**3. Using `evenlet` or `signal` as already mentioned in the similar question:**
[Timeout for python requests.get entire response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965484/timeout-for-python-requests-get-entire-response)

Comment: You never answered what the default is

Comment: Quote:You can tell Requests to stop waiting for a response after a given number of seconds with the timeout parameter. Nearly all production code should use this parameter in nearly all requests. Failure to do so can cause your program to hang indefinitely:
Note
timeout is not a time limit on the entire response download; rather, an exception is raised if the server has not issued a response for timeout seconds (more precisely, if no bytes have been received on the underlying socket for timeout seconds). If no timeout is specified explicitly, requests do not time out.

Comment: Code has a typo: import requests<new line here> from requests.adapters import TimeoutSauce

Answer (score 11):

I wanted a default timeout easily added to a bunch of code (assuming that timeout solves your problem)

This is the solution I picked up from a ticket submitted to the repository for Requests.

credit: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2011#issuecomment-477784399

The solution is the last couple of lines here, but I show more code for better context. I like to use a session for retry behaviour.

```
import requests
import functools
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter,Retry


def requests_retry_session(
        retries=10,
        backoff_factor=2,
        status_forcelist=(500, 502, 503, 504),
        session=None,
        ) -> requests.Session:
    session = session or requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(
            total=retries,
            read=retries,
            connect=retries,
            backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
            status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
            )
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    # set default timeout
    for method in ('get', 'options', 'head', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete'):
        setattr(session, method, functools.partial(getattr(session, method), timeout=30))
    return session
```

then you can do something like this:

```
requests_session = requests_retry_session()
r = requests_session.get(url=url,...
```

Answer (score 10):

Patching the documented "send" function will fix this for all requests - even in many dependent libraries and sdk's.  When patching libs, be sure to patch supported/documented functions, not TimeoutSauce - otherwise you may wind up silently losing the effect of your patch.

```
import requests

DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 180

old_send = requests.Session.send

def new_send(*args, **kwargs):
     if kwargs.get("timeout", None) is None:
         kwargs["timeout"] = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
     return old_send(*args, **kwargs)

requests.Session.send = new_send
```

The effects of not having any timeout are quite severe, and the use of a default timeout can almost never break anything - because TCP itself has default timeouts as well.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the reason of "requests.get never returns" is because `requests.get()` attempt to **connect to the host resolved with ipv6 ip first**. If something went wrong to connect that ipv6 ip and get stuck, then it retries **ipv4 ip** only if I explicit set `timeout=<N seconds>` and hit the timeout.

My solution is **monkey-patching** the python `socket` to **ignore ipv6**(or ipv4 if ipv4 not working), either [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50044152/1074998) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43950235/1074998) are works for me.

You might wondering why `curl` command is works, because `curl` connect ipv4 without waiting for ipv6 complete. You can trace the socket syscalls with `strace -ff -e network -s 10000 -- curl -vLk '<your url>'` command. For python, `strace -ff -e network -s 10000 -- python3 <your python script>` command can be used.

Answer (score 5):

Reviewed all the answers and came to conclusion that the problem still exists. On some sites requests may hang infinitely and using multiprocessing seems to be overkill. Here's my approach(Python 3.5+):

```
import asyncio

import aiohttp


async def get_http(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(conn_timeout=1, read_timeout=3) as client:
        try:
            async with client.get(url) as response:
                content = await response.text()
                return content, response.status
        except Exception:
            pass


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(get_http('http://example.com'))
loop.run_until_complete(task)
result = task.result()
if result is not None:
    content, status = task.result()
    if status == 200:
        print(content)
```

## UPDATE

If you receive a deprecation warning about using conn_timeout and read_timeout, check near the bottom of [THIS](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#aiohttp-client-timeouts) reference for how to use the ClientTimeout data structure. One simple way to apply this data structure per the linked reference  to the original code above would be:

```
async def get_http(url):
    timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=60)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=timeout) as client:
        try:
            etc.
```

Comment: @Nawaz Python 3.5+. Thank you for the question, updated the answer with Python version. It's legal Python code. Please take a look at aiohttp documentation http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: This solved my issues when other methods would not. Py 3.7. Due to deprications, had to use ... 
timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=60)
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=timeout) as client: