# Python requests module connection timeout

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm looking at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ and "Connection Timeouts" is listed as a feature.  However, when I read further, it states

> timeout is not a time limit on the entire response download; rather, an exception is raised if the server has not issued a response for timeout seconds (more precisely, if no bytes have been received on the underlying socket for timeout seconds).

That doesn't sound like a description of a connection timeout.  What I'm seeing is a connection is successful, it uploads a big file and then waits for a response.  However, the response takes a while and then timesout.

How can I set a connection timeout, but still wait for slow responses once a connection has been successful?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Related: [Python requests, how to limit received size, transfer rate, and/or total time?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22346158), [Timeout for python requests.get entire response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21965484)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The timeout is used for both the socket connect stage and the *response reading stage*. The only exception is *streamed* requests; if you set `stream=True`, the timeout cannot be applied to the reading portion. The timeout is indeed used *just* for waiting for the socket to connect or data to be received.

If you need an *overall* timeout, then use another technique, like using interrupts or eventlets: [Timeout for python requests.get entire response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965484/timeout-for-python-requests-get-entire-response)

Comment: Note that this does not mean that you can't receive a read timeout exception with `stream=True`.

Answer (score 18):

The requests (for humans) library has connection timeouts, see
- https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts

```py
r = requests.get('https://github.com', timeout=(3.05, 27))

# e.g. explicitly
conn_timeout = 6
read_timeout = 60
timeouts = (conn_timeout, read_timeout)
r = requests.get('https://github.com', timeout=timeouts)
```

The docs are not exactly explicit about which value is which in the tuple, but it might be safe to assume that it's `(connect, read)` timeouts.

Comment: This is the most practical answer to setting timeouts

Comment: The docs is not explicit, but looking the [code docstring](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/2d5517682b3b38547634d153cea43d48fbc8cdb5/requests/sessions.py#L476-L478) we can confirm that it is `(connect, read)`