# Python requests timeout not suitable when sites stream

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

The following works for 99.999% of websites but randomly found one for which it does not:

```
import requests
requests.get('http://arboleascity.com',timeout=(5,5),verify=False)
```

I have filed an issue on the project.

https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4276

Any suggestions or ideas?

I am running this in `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` so I don't really want to add in something external like eventlets or signals. But open to anything that works well.

Comment: Is the page very/infinitely long?

Comment: Go to it, I can't see anything wrong with the site. Loads super fast, fairly small size of content.

Comment: Curl it, I can't see it ever end. It looks like the page endlessly streams at 8 kBps

Comment: IMHO a success rate of the 0.0001% failure rate could also come from a network hick up. anyhow since your're successful the most time, I think it is an issue for github

Comment: Nick: you are right, hmm any suggestions on how to limit this with requests library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python requests, how to limit received size, transfer rate, and/or total time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346158/python-requests-how-to-limit-received-size-transfer-rate-and-or-total-time)

Comment: If you're "randomly finding" websites, you probably need more containment if you have literally no idea what sort of data you're going to pull down.

Comment: Nick: I think you are right, about the duplicate question, although it seems slightly different to me, in the sense that my question is specific to that site. Although the answer I am really looking for is something more robust that is presented in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It streams a SHOUTcast stream (Content-Type: audio/aacp), so there is no timeout, it just never stops streaming.

If you wanted the homepage, and not the stream, set the User-Agent header to something browser-like. If you wanted the audiostream, use `stream=True` and iterate the content - here you can also bail out if wanted.

If you are writing a scraper, you might want to check for content-type in a HEAD request before trying to fetch responses that are chunked.

Comment: Hey that worked, thanks! Although might need to implement something a little more robust.

Answer (score 1):

They're both working [exactly as documented](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts).

> The **connect timeout is the number of seconds Requests will wait for your client to establish a connection** to a remote machine (corresponding to the connect()) call on the socket. It's a good practice to set connect timeouts to slightly larger than a multiple of 3, which is the default TCP packet retransmission window.
>
> Once your client has connected to the server and sent the HTTP request, the **read timeout** is the number of seconds the client will wait for the server to send a response. (Specifically, it's **the number of seconds that the client will wait between bytes sent from the server**. In 99.9% of cases, this is the time before the server sends the first byte).

Comment: Thanks, good to know. So my question title is incorrectly tied to my problem but doesn't really help me, still up-vote as what you say is true.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the `requests`, but with the way you're accessing that specific site.

Namely, seems like `http://arboleascity.com` uses `User-Agent` header field to differentiate browsers from music players.

If you use a valid browser signature, it just returns the page HTML (`text/html`) and closes the connection:

```
$ curl -vvv -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0' http://arboleascity.com >/dev/null
...
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
...
100   118    0   118    0     0    297      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   297
* Connection #0 to host arboleascity.com left intact
```

However, if you leave `User-Agent` undefined (the default), the site streams binary content (`audio/aacp`) at ~8kbps:

```
$ curl -vvv http://arboleascity.com >/dev/null
...
< Content-Type: audio/aacp
...
< icy-notice1: <BR>This stream requires <a href="http://www.winamp.com">Winamp</a><BR>
< icy-notice2: SHOUTcast DNAS/posix(linux x64) v2.5.1.724<BR>
...
100  345k    0  345k    0     0  26975      0 --:--:--  0:00:13 --:--:--  7118^C
```

Or, [with `requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers):

```
>>> headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'}
>>> r = requests.get('http://arboleascity.com', headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right although similar to antii, this doesn't really help me. Still appreciated though so upvote.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to prevent streaming using requests?

Comment: If you wish to handle the streaming case (limit the received content size), see the linked [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346158/python-requests-how-to-limit-received-size-transfer-rate-and-or-total-time).