# Requests does not timeout

Tags: python

I am using requests in python for checking malicious headers. My code is working, but this one specific ip does not close the connection nor does it timeout.

```
def check():
  ...
  r=requests.head('https://50.79.153.56',verify=False,timeout=(4,4))
  ...
```

Using curl i found out that the site keeps sending the same sequence of bytes

```
curl -v -k https://50.79.153.56
....
> ~▒}#▒!}!}!} }8}"}&} } } } }#}$▒#}%}&i+G}<}'}"}(}"▒▒~~▒}#▒!}!}!} }
```

Using this , brings success!

```
curl -v -k https://50.79.153.56 -m 3
...
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 3000 milliseconds with 51 bytes received
```

How should the timeout flag in requests look like so similar occurrences do not happen?
I tried both python2.7 and 3.x but the result is the same.

Comment: i dont get what is problem ? u want send request to api and want set timeout ?

Comment: -m stands for maximum time allowed for the request so it is kind of opposite to timeout

Comment: @NozarSafari i just want to check the headers , nothing else. But the connection is never closed and my function does not have any results

Comment: @zRAA is there a similar flag in requests?

Comment: timeout =10 in requests mean time out 10 seconds

Comment: @NozarSafari but the problem is , it never timeouts

Comment: ok wait i write a sample for u

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

try :
    r=requests.head('https://50.79.153.56',verify=False,timeout=4)
except :
     print("Time out Happened")
```

it is sample with 4 sec time out

for python2.7

```
    r=requests.head('https://50.79.153.56',verify=False,timeout=urllib3.Timeout(4,4))
```

Comment: as you can see in my sample code , i am already using timeout=, but as i said it is not working nor is it timeouting. run the code

Comment: u use touple for timeout i dont know what it mean `timeout=(4,4)` this code work i test it! even with that touple work too try reinstall `requests`

Comment: are u using `requests` or it is other module ?

Comment: python
Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:30:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> r=requests.head('https://50.79.153.56',verify=False,timeout=4)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)

it just hangs

Comment: ok your pyrhon is 2.7 mention it in question . it is python 3.x code and u need `pip install requests` can u change python version or u must use 2.7?

Comment: Though I don't know why yet, I have the same behavior on Python3: it throws an InsecureRequestWarning error, and never time-outs; but if you change to verify=True, it time-outs after 4 sec.

Comment: look at link address `https://..` SSL need verify . u can't set it False , i edited answer for python2.7 too

Comment: Yes, I figured out now. Time-out clause is for a non-successful connection. It will not time-out when connected and receiving data. To do that, I guess you should control the total connection time by other means (e.g. using a thread which makes the connection, and killing it after a specific amount of time)

Comment: @Kalma so this is expected behavior ?

Comment: Yes. But you can control the total connection time (or size) which is what you need: Take a look to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346158/python-requests-how-to-limit-received-size-transfer-rate-and-or-total-time