# Skip a link from a list when scraping part with python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

first post here, countless of other times I encountered problems that were already solved but can't figure this out.

The following while loop is intented to download the text contained in a list of urls (3 in the example). It does it for all the links but this link ([this](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1004724/0001144204-14-042745.txt)), the 3rd in the example, takes very long. By opening it in the browser it appears like it has a number of jpg images. (the txt represents a number of documents merged in 1 file; in this specific example, some of the documents were images).

The images can be recognized in the text thanks to these lines before them:

```
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>GRAPHIC
<SEQUENCE>7
<FILENAME>tex99-4_pg01.jpg
<DESCRIPTION>GRAPHIC
<TEXT>
begin 644 tex99-4_pg01.jpg
```

and they are followed by this code:

```
end
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
```

Is there any way to SKIP that link if the download takes too long so to make the scraper faster? I am looking to apply this code to 320K of these links and would like to find a way to make the download faster rather than "cutting" the txt I get afterwards

This is what I am currently using to scrape:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

list_of_links = ['https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000298/0001193125-14-321757.txt',  
                 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1002225/0000903423-14-000495.txt', 
                 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1004724/0001144204-14-042745.txt'] # the one with the images
number_of_urls = len(list_of_links)  # get number of links to iterate them
i = 0         

column_names = ["Filing text"]
DF = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

while i < number_of_urls: 
    print("File #", i+1,"\tis being processed") # print this to visually see how long each download takes
    DF.loc[i, "Filing text"] = requests.get(list_of_links[i]).text
    i += 1
```

Comment: oh man -- don't append to your dataframe like that. Populate late when in instantiate: `pandas.DataFrame([requests.get(link).text for link in list_of_links], columns=columns_names)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `requests` library, you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22347526/8294752

In your case, since it's always just text data, looking at the content length should be enough.

On a different note, it's always good practice to include a `timeout` to a requests call. This will not solve your problem, as a timeout only considers the time during which the server does not answer, but not having it can create problems, especially in a loop.

**EDIT**

This could be a working solution to your problem (I've incorporated Paul H's feedback here as well):

Please note that I swapped the second and the last URL in the list, so you can better assess the time savings. Also, remember that you will have some `None` if the df at the end and to set a meaningful `CONTENT_LENGTH_LIMIT` depending on the data that you want to download

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

list_of_links = ['https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000298/0001193125-14-321757.txt',
                 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1004724/0001144204-14-042745.txt',  
                 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1002225/0000903423-14-000495.txt', 
                 ] # the one with the images     

column_names = ["Filing text"]
DF = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

CONTENT_LENGTH_LIMIT = 8070869 # just a limit which is lower than the size of the third link
def fetch_text(url):
    print("Url", url,"\tis being processed") # print this to visually see how long each download takes
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=5)
        if int(r.headers.get('Content-Length')) > CONTENT_LENGTH_LIMIT:
            print("Url", url,"\thas been skipped")
            return None
        else: 
            text = "".encode() # the chunks are in bytes
            for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
                text += chunk
        return text.decode()
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
        print("The server did not respond in time")
        # here it will return None, you can filter it later

DF = pd.DataFrame([fetch_text(link) for link in list_of_links],
                    columns=column_names)
```

Comment: thank you - great material. will include that and see if I can solve

Comment: @arabinelli - Thank you - this looks awesome.

Comment: Glad it's helpful!