# python requests synchronous callback

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, callback

I am using the python requests library to download data from a web server e.g:

```
import requests

fname = 'guppy-0.1.10.tar.gz'
url = 'https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/g/guppy/' + fname
r = requests.get(url)
open(fname, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Which is working as expected.

But I am needing to download data (and save) from a web server that is continuously streaming data.

So is there a callback function that I can use with the requests api that lets me do this?

Comment: When downloading files, enable `stream` for the request. Try `requests.get(url, tream=True)`.

Comment: if you add this as a reply ill award it the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When downloading files, you should enable the `stream` option.

```py
requests.get(url, stream=True)
```

Of course, this has some limitations in some cases.

- If the file is large
- The internet is slow

In the above cases, a timeout exception will be thrown.
If you face such an issue, see [how to fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346158/python-requests-how-to-limit-received-size-transfer-rate-and-or-total-time#answer-22347526).