# Why is default timeout for python requests.get() different for different machines

Tags: python, linux, python-requests

My program wants to get the webpage contents on a private IP(10.0.0.0/8) in internal network.
I am using python requests.get() for that purpose.

---

I went through question [Why doesn't requests.get() return? What is the default timeout that requests.get() uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782142/why-doesnt-requests-get-return-what-is-the-default-timeout-that-requests-get#) but I did not get much help

1. On what basis is the default timeout for python get request determined ?
2. Is it dependent on the TCP stack configuration ? Which file hosts that configuration ?

Comment: You don't give a lot of information about *which machines / platforms* you are testing this on. My guess is that the timeout is being managed by the OS, not the library. 45 seconds (or some multiple thereof) used to be common, but that was a while ago.

Comment: I am using a Centos distribution running a 2.6 kernel version

Answer (score -2):

1. Again, the default timeout is `None`, you can dig into the library files in your OS (the path is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/` in my Mac OSX)

   - two files to look into is `api.py` and `sessions.py`
   - for `timeout` part, line 275 file `sessions.py`
2. You can read the document here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts (the Note part)

Comment: Thanks Joe for the answer but that part does not explain why the time out is different for different machines ...
I suspect it has something to do with OS TCP stack configuration but I am not able to find any documentation

Comment: Welcome to SO. This would be better suited as a comment, I know you need to get a certain level of cred to comment, but hopefully this can help you with improving your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer