# Python requests not giving back >>> prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7, get, python-requests

I have requests installed already and yes it is up to date. Importing requests, writing down headers and writing down URL is fine. They return the `>>>` prompt. When I write:

```
>>> res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

nothing returns. I don't even get the >>> prompt. everything else i write after this do not respond, does not have the >>> and is only black in colour.

Comment: Can you access the URL otherwise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't requests.get() return? What is the default timeout that requests.get() uses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782142/why-doesnt-requests-get-return-what-is-the-default-timeout-that-requests-get)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in a timeout, allowing the call to stop after a certain amount of time.

Replace

`res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)`

with

```
r = requests.get(
    url,
    headers=headers,
    timeout=5
)
```