# MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 -> Extremely Slow Requests Library

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, networking, python-requests

In python, when I try to use the requests library or any other library that requires connecting to the internet, the response comes extremely slow.

Code as simple as the following can take 2 to 5 minutes.

```
import requests
requests.get('https://www.google.com')
```

The same code finishes within 1 second on my Linux machine.

If I use non-python method to achieve the same thing, i.e. curl

```
curl 'https://www.google.com'
```

The response comes in less than 1 second.

What may be causing this? Where should I be looking? I don't know much about networking or Macs in general, so can someone help me debug with detailed instructions?

Comment: do you have *MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6* or *Linux machine*?

Comment: Its a MacBook Pro (MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6)

Comment: How did you install python3 and requests module?

Comment: python3 and pip3 with brew. requests with pip3 inside virtual env.

Comment: @Astar, have you found what caused this?

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, by default `requests` uses infinite timeout.

Try setting different connect and read timeouts and see what is the exception.

```
r = requests.get('https://github.com', timeout=(10, 30))
```

You might want to print verbose logs to see what's going on:

```
logging.basicConfig() 
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True
```

See for the reference and context:

- http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts
- [Why doesn't requests.get() return? What is the default timeout that requests.get() uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782142/why-doesnt-requests-get-return-what-is-the-default-timeout-that-requests-get)
- https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/3070