# Airflow Python-Operator task running for forever with requests.get()

Tags: python-requests, airflow, python-operator

I am having an issue while tying to run a dag, particularly using a request.get() inside a python operator. This request.get() is causing the task to run "forever" without getting an actual response and this is also creating a message from scheduler: "The scheduler does not appear to be running. Last heartbeat was receiver X minutes ago". If I removed "response = request.get(somewebsite.com)" the dag runs perfectly. I tried running the same code outside airflow (jupyter notebook) with the requests.get() and works perfectly. The issue happens only when running the dag in webserver. any thoughts or ideas on how to fix this?

code:

```
import requests
import airflow
import pendulum
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
    dag = DAG(
        dag_id="receive_requests_test",
        start_date=pendulum.today('UTC').add(days=-7),
        schedule=None
)

def _get_request():
        x = requests.get("https://spacelaunchnow-prod-east.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/media/launch_images/falcon2520925_image_20231014184958.png")
        print(x.status_code)
print_request_1 = PythonOperator(
task_id="request_test_print",
python_callable=_get_request,dag=dag,
```

)

Comment: For the request get hanging you need to specify a timeout. Pls refer this answer link below . There also maybe an issue with reaching the URL from your airflow running on docker.  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782142/why-doesnt-requests-get-return-what-is-the-default-timeout-that-requests-get&ved=2ahUKEwigkYWkp5CEAxViF1kFHfaeAyEQFnoECB0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw0uSgEwCzfHM7imyctycxiR